# Meshlab nan coords and degenerated faces

Tags: nan, point-clouds, meshlab, coords

In my point cloud I can't execute "normal" commands and "filters" because they do not have triangulation faces, so a message appears "Meshlab nan coords and degenerate faces". How do I solve this problem? Can I generate faces in my cloud when I have only points?

Comment: Hi. Did you manage this task ? I have the similar one to do ...

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of Q value(depthToDisparity Matrix). Some libraries generate wrong values
[Q value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04Iv5.png)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it